# Using RPC in Linux Kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rpc

In Linux user space programming, we use RPCGEN for RPC programming. In Linux Kernel module, is there any interface like RPCGEN for programming?

Comment: I hesitate to even ask why you're contemplating RPC mechanisms inside the kernel... but my curiosity gets me. What're you trying to do? :)

Comment: For example, how the NFS implements the RPC mechanism?

Comment: As far as I know, all the funny RPC in NFS is handled via the userspace `portmap` daemon. (And even then, `2049` is often just hardcoded, it's easier on firewall admins that way.)

Answer (score 0):

NFS client (and server as well) is kernel-based and NFS protocol is based on Sun RPC, so have a look at it's implementation.